# Required input with error handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I'm trying to program the Blackjack card game in Python. 
Within the player class, I would like to define a loop that would require the player to decide to either "hit" or "stand" (Blackjack rules). Unless the input is correct (either 'S' for stand or 'H' for hit), the loop needs to cycle until the player inputs one of those 2 options.

Here is my code for this specific part:

```
while True:
    try:
        D = input('What is your decision, stand or hit? [press S for stand and H for hit]: ')
        if D in ['S', 'H'] is False:
            1/0
    except:
        print('Incorrect input, please try again (S for stand and H for hit)!')
        continue
    else:
        if D == 'S':
            print('OK, you decided to stand!')
        else:
            print('OK, you decided to hit. You will receive a 3rd card!')
        break
```

So the idea is that unless the decision is right ('S' or 'H'), an error is created, but so far, the code doesn't work properly yet... I think there is a small glitch....

Any proposals?
Kind regards,

L

Comment: Do you know what e.g. `'Foo' in ['S', 'H'] is False` evaluates to? It may surprise you.

Comment: What are you expecting in except? You should expect something in try except block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write:

```
if D not in ['S', 'H']:
```

And the whole code would be shorter and more readable without the exception:

```
while True:
    D = input('What is your decision, stand or hit? [press S for stand and H for hit]: ')
    if D not in ['S', 'H']:
        print('Incorrect input, please try again (S for stand and H for hit)!')
        continue
    else:
        if D == 'S':
            print('OK, you decided to stand!')
        else:
            print('OK, you decided to hit. You will receive a 3rd card!')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of exception there, you can just do:

```
while True:    # infinite loop
    D = input('What is your decision, stand or hit? [press S for stand and H for hit]: ')
    if D == "S":
        #do some
        break 
    elif D == "H":
        # Hit some.
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect input, please try again (S for stand and H for hit)!')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, this is even cleaner!

Comment: @mcluka you are welcome! don't worry about the down vote... sometimes you can control what people thinks even if they are wrong

Comment: @mcluka don't worry, sometimes I don't understand it either, but when I see something like that I try to fix it, so I up voted your question because it was a very good one, with example, short sample of code, showing effort, I mean, it has everything... well I'm happy I could help you, don't forget to accept if it was helpul, I have always loved to help